# Spring Security постоянно перекидывает на failureUrl

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Добрый день. Начал разбираться с Spring Security. При авторизации логин и пароль правильные(в логах userDetailsService вижу, что user вытащен из БД), exception никакой не выскакивает, но перекидывает на failureUrl.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**","/js/**","/images/**","/pages/registration.html",
            "/pages/forgot_password.html","/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()

            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/unauthorized")

            .and()
     .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
            .usernameParameter("j_login")
            .failureUrl("/login.html?true&&")
            .permitAll()

            .and()
     .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws      
UsernameNotFoundException {
    System.out.println(login);
    Customer customer = service.getCustomer(login);
    if (customer == null){
        System.out.println(login + " not found");
    }else{
        System.out.println(customer);
    }

    Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet<>();
    roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(customer.getRole().name()));

    return new User(customer.getLogin(), customer.getPassword(), roles);
}
```

подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так. Спасибо.

Comment: 1) Почему вы не бросаете `UsernameNotFoundException` когда `customer == null`? 2) выкрутите логгирование на уровень и смотрите, что в логах

Comment: Так в том-то и дело, что он не null...

Comment: Это я понимаю, просто вижу, что код не корректный и сообщаю вам по ходу. Что в логах? Если у вас Spring Boot приложение, то запустите с `--debug`.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin подскажите, пожалуйста, в Security 4 AuthenticationProvider нужен или если я использую UserDetailsService -  не надо?

Comment: Насколько понимаю, естественно, нужен. Это совершенно разные сущности.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin Я унаследовал своему пользователю UserDetails и его использовал в UserSetailsService. Настроил провайдера - ничего. К стати, UserDetailService ключает в себя реализацию UserDetails и UserDetailsService одновременно. Короче, только зря переделывал свою реализацию. Я продебажил - где-то в глубине Security, password не подходит, хотя до этого момента везде пароль правильный...Что может быть?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. ДЛя правильной авторизации нужен не только UserDetailsService, но и AuthenticationProvider.